# How can I consistently get a good logistic regression fit?

Tags: fitting

I'm executing the command

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, c/(1 + a Exp[-b x]), {a, b, c}, x]
```

with the data being

```
data = { {0, 15576}, {10, 15935}, {20, 16326}, 
{30, 18235}, {40, 21680}, {50, 22927}, {60, 28667}, 
{70, 41674}, {80, 50020}, {90, 75979}, {100, 148700}, 
{110, 197200}, {120, 212801}, {130, 215499}, {140, 227511}}
```

and I'm getting a nonsensical result.  It's a horrible fit.  I've tried various `Method` options and I always get a bad fit.  My goal is to try to replicate what a TI-84 would give.

I don't know enough about this stuff to know why the TI-84 always seems to give reasonable fits but *Mathematica* does not.

Comment: [Here](ftp://ftp.ti.com/pub/graph-ti/calc-apps/info/logistic.txt) is a shallow description of how TI calculators do logistic fitting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to give some reasonable start values for the fit.
E.g. try

```
fitFkt = NonlinearModelFit[data,c/(1 + a Exp[-b x]), {a, {b, 0.1}, {c, Max[data[[All, 2]]]}}, x]
```

As you can see from `Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[fitFkt[x], {x, 0, 150}]]`, the fit is quite ok.

Comment: Indeed, the second example under "scope" in the documentation for `NonlinearModelFit` is exactly this kind of thing. Apparently, if you don't specify initial conditions, it assumes initial values `1`. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html

Comment: Now, suppose one was given a different set of data with a logistic trend. How does one pick out a reasonable initial guess for `b`? :)

Comment: If another data set shows a similar trend and if you do not know which initial value for `b` you should chose, then you could try to change the `Method`. E.g. `NonlinearModelFit[data, 
 c/(1 + a Exp[-b x]), {a, b, {c, Max[data[[All, 2]]]}}, x, 
 Method -> "Newton"]` leads to the same result without any initial guess for `b`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a rather *ad hoc* procedure for logistic fitting that I use:

```
dat = N[{{0, 15576}, {10, 15935}, {20, 16326}, {30, 18235}, {40, 21680}, {50, 22927},
         {60, 28667}, {70, 41674}, {80, 50020}, {90, 75979}, {100, 148700}, {110, 197200},
         {120, 212801}, {130, 215499}, {140, 227511}}];

(* rough estimate of asymptote *)
c0 = Max[dat[[All, 2]]];

dm = DeleteCases[dat, {_, c0}];
(* linear regression of transformed data *)
{a0, b0} = {Exp[-\[FormalK]], \[FormalM]} /.
 FindFit[Transpose[{dm[[All, 1]], Log[#/(c0 - #)] &[dm[[All, 2]]]}],
         \[FormalK] + \[FormalM] \[FormalX], {\[FormalK], \[FormalM]}, \[FormalX]];

{at, bt, ct} = {\[FormalA], \[FormalB], \[FormalC]} /. 
          FindFit[dat, \[FormalC]/(1 + \[FormalA] Exp[-\[FormalB] \[FormalX]]),
                  {{\[FormalA], a0}, {\[FormalB], b0}, {\[FormalC], c0}}, \[FormalX]]
   {874.6314992136595, 0.07113415632530808, 242526.3213562982}
```

We obtain something a bit useful:

```
Plot[ct/(1 + at Exp[-bt x]), {x, 0, 140}, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]], Point[dat]}]
```

[image: a logistic fit]

FWIW, I also tried the problem on my TI-83 Plus. Using the built-in logistic regression function, I obtained `{a, b, c} = {874.6224282, 0.0711340415, 242526.4026}`. Pretty close...

Comment: I figured you'd want to see a way to handle sigmoidally-shaped data in general instead of just the specific data set in the OP, so I presented one of the usual ways.