# forecasting for mortality using a logistic regression

Tags: fitting

I need to know how to do a forecasting for mortality using a logistic regression, can somebody help?

```
data = {{1., 0.75}, {2., 0.89}, {3., 0.42}, {4., 0.99}, {5., 0.84},
        {6., 0.34}, {7., 0.83}, {8., 0.93}, {9., 0.76}, {10., 0.11}};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, b Exp[m x]/(1 + b Exp[m x]), {b, m}, x]
```

the data that has been input is fake, i want to know if am doing a forecasting what kind of data should i input?

Comment: See [How can I consistently get a good logistic regression fit?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23998/how-can-i-consistently-get-a-good-logistic-regression-fit) may be a dup

Comment: Pleae note that there is [`LogitModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogitModelFit.html) and in this case the more general [`GeneralizedLinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneralizedLinearModelFit.htm) to do this. A [*Logistic Regression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is a linear model with the Logit-function as its *link function*.

Answer (score 1):

So while I can't see your data to make sense, in principle this should work:

```
data = {{1., 0.75}, {2., 0.89}, {3., 0.42}, {4., 0.99}, {5.,0.84}, 
        {6., 0.34}, {7., 0.83}, {8., 0.93}, {9., 0.76}, {10.,0.11}};

lm = LogitModelFit[ data, x, x ];

lm[11]
```

> 0.50088